# Mongo Get collection names function db.getCollectionNames() is Not working in sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-collection

I was getting all collection names by function db.getCollectionNames().

But as soon as I started sharding, function db.getCollectionNames() is Not working.

How to get all collection names in database when sharding is active?

Comment: Does very much sound like you have the wrong database selected. Check which database you are on before you issue.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I have right database selected.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB? Do you perhaps have a version 3 shell connected to older MongoDB instances? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have selected a database: `use <database>`.

If it still does not work, try `show collections`.

Comment: "show collections" work on local database without sharding. But same not works on database with sharding.